# Existing function or algorithm to alter Strings

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I am looking for an existing function or algorithm to alter strings in order to make it undetectable.

For example:
Input:

```
mother
```

Ouput:

```
room
```

the principle is that we apply instructions on the input to get another word which  has a meaning.
**Edit1**
the ouput should be a comprehensible word and not exactly formed with the same alphabets of the input .
input:mother
may will
ouput:home(the principale is somthing if we read it we will understand the meaning).
**Edit2**
What i look for is altering data (words) in this case ,in order to avoid the using of crypto methods that attract attention,our aim to hide words by altering with anothers.

Comment: This is a very bad attempt at encrypting data...

Comment: I would rather just use a Ceaser Cipher for simple encryption.

Comment: Why not map `mother -> othermay`? It's almost as secure and much more fun,

Comment: @kalsowerus Thank you for you response,
if you can just clarify more to me because i am newbie in cryptography field.

Comment: @bradimus Thanx but  i didn't understand the approch?!!

Comment: Google it, a Ceasar Cipher simply shifts every letter by n amount. a -> c, b -> d, c -> e...
Another approach is the slightly more advanced Ployalphabetic Cipher which uses a keyword to shift letters by different amounts.
Both are easy to implement and the polyalphabetic cipher is actually quite difficult to crack without the use of software.

Comment: Thanks again @kalsowerus but Ceasar Cipher using shifting i will lose the meaning of the word (the ouput).
i need to keep or to have a word  with meaning in output

Comment: I don't think the OP wants to have encryption. But @YassineBadri please clarify your exact needs. Why do you want to alter the strings?

Comment: If every 'encrypted' word must be another actual word you may have no other choice than to make a list of all words you can think of (or all you know you will need) and shift them using this list like a Ceasar Cipher would using the alphabet.

Comment: @SteffenHarbich 
i need somthing to alter words with just have another word with a meaning  .
i can take any example of a word at the last i get another word different from the first and also have a meaning in order hide the word in input in another word which has a meaning too.
mother --> chair(or any  other word)

Comment: @kalsowerus the using of a list of word demands huge dictionnary.

Comment: Its your only chance. You need a word with a meaning, you cannot generate it. A randomly generated word has a very low chance of having a meaning.

Comment: @kalsowerus  What a bad chance ,Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are after is called a [substitution cipher](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher).

What you would need would be a corpus of words, such as a dictionary and a hash map or any other key value collection.

You would then go over the source text and for every word, you check to see if it is in the hash map. If it is, then replace it with the hash map equivalent. If not, select a random word from the dictionary and assign that to the word in the hash map. The word is then removed from the dictionary to avoid the risk of having different words mapping to the same words.

This would allow you to end up with a string of words. To decrypt it, you would need swap the key-values within the hash map, meaning that the keys would become values and the values would become keys. You would then go over the encrypted string and replace the words with the their respective values within the hash map.

Note though that once you loose the hash map you will have essentially lost the key to your encrypted string.

Comment: Thank you for your answering but it seems that the result with no meaning  which is our aim.the result should another word that differ from the first and also comprehensible.

Comment: I doubt that will be possible. Altering words while the sentence should still make sense will be extremely difficult because the same input-word will always have to be replaced by the same output-word.